# Undecorate JInternalFrame on MacOS

Tags: java, swing, macos

I am trying to undecorate a `JInternalFrame`, i.e. remove the default titlebar using the following code;

```
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame.getUI();
ui.getNorthPane().setPrefrredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
```

I works on windows but the second line throws a NullPointerException on MacOS

Any ideas why and how to get round it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, the JInternalFrame doesn't have a north pane. Only execute the code on none Mac OS platforms;

```
// only remove the northpanel for none Mac OS
if(!(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS"))){
    BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI();
    ui.getNorthPane().setPrefrredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
}
```

So much about cross platform :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a Mac so I don't know what is causing the problem.

A JInternalFrame without the title bar loses its ability to be dragged. You should be able to accomplish the same goal by just adding a JPanel to the desktop. You would need to set the bounds of the panel. You might also want to use one of the internal frame custom borders on the panel:

```
UIManager.getBorder("InternalFrame.paletteBorder");
UIManager.getBorder("InternalFrame.optionDialogBorder");
```

Or maybe another option is to use:

```
internalFrame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
```

This will replace the title bar with a small palette that can be used to drag the internal frame without the buttons or title.

Comment: "A JInternalFrame without the title bar loses its ability to be dragged" -- but it still can be resized ;)

Comment: @ivan I have custom code to handle the resizing and window dragging.