# May i can use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog for dispay JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, frame, jinternalframe

May i can use `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` for display `JInternalFrame`?

I tried following code:

```
OPD.Registration opdRegister = new OPD.Registration(); 
//OPD.Registration is extending JInternalFrame    

int ns=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, opdRegister, "Billing", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
// i am trying to call opdregister in this Confirm Dialog Box.
```

By using above code that display dialog box with `JInternalFrame` but it not display proper. It display only title bar. Other data are cut from the `JInternalFrame`.

How can I increase size of this dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, although a `JInternalFrame` is intended for use in a [`JDesktopPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). If you're seeing only the title bar, verify that your content has a [preferred size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and `pack()` the internal frame, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091329/230513).

Answer (score 0):

```
yourJInternalFrame obt=new yourJInternalFrame ();
obt.pack();
obt.setVisible(true);
intns=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,obt,"Billing",
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```