# View JInternalFrames without JDesktopPanes

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

As we know JInternalFrame cannot run..we have to set it to a JDesktopPane
But I heard from one of my friends that JInternalFrame can run.
Is that possible..?
Is there any code for main method ...?

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you are trying to do, and also preferably what you've tried so far.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to run `JInternalFrame` without adding it into a `JDesktopPane`. Try running the JIF on a JFrame for the main method to have a view the layout.

Comment: better could be without !, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, without any shouting !!!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, “JInternalFrame cannot run”; they don’t have legs. But if you claim that they cannot be used without a `JDesktopPane`, where do you get that “knowledge” from? And why don’t you try for yourself? It takes less than five minutes:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class IFrames
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.setContentPane(new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
      createFrame("Left"), createFrame("right") ));
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static JInternalFrame createFrame(String title)
  {
    final JInternalFrame f1 = new JInternalFrame(title, true, true);
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(title));
    return f1;
  }
}
```

Simple answer: no one prevents you from using them without a `JDesktopPane` though using them with it is more natural. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) says: “Generally, you add JInternalFrames to a JDesktopPane.”

Well, “Generally” does not preclude exemptions.

By the way `JOptionPane.showInternal…Dialog` is a typical example of an application of using a `JInternalFrame` without a `JDesktopPane`.

Comment: +1 for `JOptionPane.showInternal*Dialog`; a related example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19905717/230513).

Comment: Is it possible to launch without even using `JFrame` component?

Comment: @zIronManBox: *internal* frames need an ancestor, whether it is a `Window`, `Frame` or `Dialog` doesn’t matter. If all you are interested in, is showing it without surrounding decoration, setting the `JInternalFrame` as content pane of a `JWindow` would do, though for most use cases, you’d better use a `JFrame` or `JDialog` plus `setUndecorated(true);`. Keep in mind that the internal frame’s controls will not control the host window. Maybe, you actually want [look&feel decorated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated-boolean-) frames.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response. I wanted to understand if internal frame could control the host window. Now I know.